# Bernouli Trial Probability of Stopping After X Trials

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The probability of a trial being a success if 0.30

Trials are repeated until 6 are successful.

I'm asked to find the probability that the trials are ended after the 7th. (The 6 successful trials requirement has been reached).

I've identified it as a Bernoulli trial, and I believe I would simply use the binomial expression formula,

b(n, x, p) with n being 7, x being 6 and p being 0.30.

Is this correct?

**Update:** To clarify, it is meant that no more trials will occur after the 7th trial. This means that once the 7th trial has been completed, there have been 6 trials that were successful.

Comment: There is some disagreement over what the favoured event *is* meant to be.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer replaces a previous one based upon a mistaken interpretation of the problem.

There are two possibilities:

- the first 6 trials in a row were successful; in this case a 7th trial becomes unnecessary; the probability of this situation is $0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 = 0.000729$.
- one and only one of the first 6 trials failed, and then we need a successful 7th; since the probability of a single failure is $0.7$, this gives

$$(0.7 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 + \\
\cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.7 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 + \\
\cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.7 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 + \\
\cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.7 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 + \\
\cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.7 \cdot 0.3 + \\
\cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.7) \cdot 0.3 = \\
6 \cdot 0.3 ^6 \cdot 0.7 = 0.0030618 .$$

Since you want either of the two situations, sum these two probabilities to get $0.0037908$.

Comment: That's the probability of one failure followed by six *consecutive* successes, and ending *on* the seventh trial.  This isn't anything near what was asked, which was the probability of the sixth success occurring *after* the seventh trial.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: You might be right. I might be misinterpreting the statement of the problem (the OP's formulation is a little sloppy). Do you mean that he asks for 6 successes out of 7 trials regardless of whether they are consecutive or not? If so, I shall modify my answer. You say *"the probability of the sixth success occurring after the seventh trial"* (i.e. there are at least 8 trials) but the OP writes *"the trials are ended after the 7th"*. Are you sure of your interpretetation? Mine is probably wrong, but yours seems so too.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: Please check the new version of the answer that correctly captures the information given by the problem.

Comment: The new version (correctly) calculates the probability that the trials are ended *on or before* the seventh trial; not that they are ended *after* the seventh.  However, this *may* be that where as I read "*are ended after this*" as "*the end comes after this*" you read it as "*after this, the end has already come*."

Answer (score 1):

No you are wrong because if 6 trials are correct in a row then we stop.

Comment: Can you offer any advice to point me towards the correct solution?

Comment: eliminate the possibility that 6 trials are correct in a row from your calculation. The probability that 6 are correct in a row is $0.3^6$

Comment: And say the trials were ended are the 10th trial, I would have to remove all probabilities from 6 to 9?

Comment: Yes you would need to do that.

Comment: I guess you wanted to write this as a comment to the answer given by @Tunococ.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** Consider 7 Bernoulli trials. The problem asks for the probability that 2 or more of them are failures. The complement of this event is the event in which 0 or 1 of the trials are failures.

*Side Note:* The number of successes (or failures) in 7 Bernoulli trials can be regarded as a Binomial random variable.

Comment: Indeed.  To end **after** trial *seven* we need **at most** *five* successes in the first *seven* trials.  We don't want the experiment to end *on or before* the seventh trial.